# In Mario Party 4, what is the reward if you win the '5 turns left lottery'?

Tags: mario-party-4

In Mario Party 4, if you pass through the lottery house, you get a lottery ticket, that is used in the '5 turns left' event.

That lottery ticket has 3 random faces, chosen randomly with the characters in the game.

What do you get if you win this lottery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Lucky_Party_Ticket) if you manage to match up all three pictures during the 5 turns left lottery, you win a star.

Comment: @Steven: But there are four ways to match all of them, so you multiply it by 4 again. In other words, you just have to have the second and third match the first one - it doesn't matter what the first one is. You can't "fail" on the first face, so it's 1/16.